# applying a list to an entered function to check for tautology

Tags: haskell, lambda

I want to write a function in haskell which determines whether a boolean function (entered with a lambda-expression in ghci) is a tautology or not.
The input should look like this:

```
taut n (\[x..] -> ... == ...)

taut 3 (\[x,y,z] -> ((x||y)||z) == (x||(y||z)) )
```

I've already created all possible boolean combinations with

```
combinations n = replicateM n [True,False] 

cmb n = concat (combinations n)
```

but now I need a function which takes these elements of the list and inserts them into the n variables in then entered function.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not really homerwork, it's an extra assignement for a module at university...we can do it if we want, but it's not required - but I want to do it because I want to at least somehow understand haskell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `combinations` function already produces a list of lists of length `n` containing all possible permutations of `True` and `False`. You do **not** need to use `concat`; the result already includes all possible entries to your function. This is the case because the function you're checking already expects a list (it's in the form of `\[a,b,c...]`).

That is, for an `fn` taking a list of length 3, `combinations 3` would be:

```
[[True,True,True],[True,True,False],[True,False,True],[True,False,False],
 [False,True,True],[False,True,False],[False,False,True],[False,False,False]]
```

Each element of this list is a *list*; you can pass them into the function you're checking (the one that might be a tautology) directly. Given the list above, all you have to do is try each element.

EDIT (trying to clarify a bit):

You want a function `taut` that takes *another* function of type `[Bool] -> Bool` and determines whether or not that function is a tautology. This means that `taut` will have a type like `Int -> ([Bool] -> Bool) -> Bool`. Let's say you start it like this:

```
taut :: Int -> ([Bool] -> Bool) -> Bool
taut n fn = ...
```

Now, `n` is the length and `fn` is the function. Your `combinations` function takes `n` and returns every possible valid *input* to `fn`. Note that `fn` expects a `[Bool]` and that `combinations n` is a `[[Bool]]`, which means each element can be an input to `fn`. Knowing this, all you need to do is apply `fn` to each element of `combinations n` and see if the result is always the same.

In your `taut` function, you do not have to worry about how variables inside the function being tested are assigned. When you're actually writing that function, if it's in the form of `\[x,y,z]->...`, `x`, `y` and `z` are going to be assigned within it thanks to pattern matching.

Comment: Yes, I've already wondered if I really need to put them into one list, but I thought maybe I could use this list and somehow "count up" and insert the boolean values into the variables...but that's really where the problem starts - I thought I might start testing how I could input the lambda-function into the code, so I typed                            `taut [x,y,z] = (\[x,y,z] -> ((x||y)||z) == (x||(y||z)) )` to see whether I could insert boolean values for x,y,z , but even that gives me a "no instance..from a use of 'print'" error which I don't really understand...

Comment: I'm a little confused about how exactly you expect the `taut` function to work. I thought you wanted it to take the lambda and try every combination of inputs. Are you thinking of doing it some other way? Also, the `taut` in your comment seems completely different from the `taut` in your question--the first one takes a number and a function; the second one seems to take two lists (Int -> [Bool] -> Bool vs [Bool] -> [Bool] -> Bool).

Comment: The second sentence is exactly how I want it to work...my "taut" function in the comment above was just a test in which I could see how I could insert the values to get closer to a solution - but apparently it doesn't work anyway and I doubt that Haskell works like this too.

Comment: Right. I'm going to try to clarify my answer.

Comment: Oh, and regarding your "no instance..." error: you probably got it by typing in a value that was a function. It just means ghci did not know how to print the value you gave it, and it doesn't know how to turn a function into a string.

Comment: That really helped a lot...I even figured out how to apply a function argument in the parameters by remembering my basic math before I saw your answer...I think I'm now close to the actual solution, as I applied the list of booleans to my taut function with `taut n fx = map fx(combinations n)` - now I'm getting a list of [True,True..] and I'm currently figuring out how to combine those to 1 single output if all are True.

Comment: and it's done - `taut n fx = and(map fx(combinations n))` is working perfectly. Looking back it all seems so simple :/ I really appreciate your help, I think it brought me a lot further on my way to figure out what I'm doing

Comment: Good to hear you got it workin--my goal was to just clarify enough for you to get the answer yourself without giving it away. It'll become simpler once you've written a bunch of programs in Haskell. A note on style: you can replace parentheses with `.` and `$`, so you can have `taut n fx = and . map fn $ combinations n` which is a little easier to read (in my opinion).