# Recursive tautology-checker in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, logic

(I'm aware that there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461283/applying-a-list-to-an-entered-function-to-check-for-tautology) on SO, but I don't think it's a dupe because the function I'm trying to implement is recursive and doesn't use lists or lambda expressions. I'd like to know how to implement it this way even if they are functionally equivalent, mainly for better understanding Haskell.)

I'm learning how to make functions that check whether a given Boolean function is a tautology. Here is a sample function from the book I'm reading that checks for Boolean functions with 1 variable:

```
valid1 :: (Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
valid1 bf = (bf True) && (bf False)
```

and for 2 and 3 variables:

```
valid2 :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
valid2 bf = (bf True True)
            && (bf True False)
            && (bf False True)
            && (bf False False)

valid3 :: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Bool
valid3 bf = and [ bf p q r | p <- [True,False],
                             q <- [True,False],
                             r <- [True,False]]
```

But it seems to me that there should be a better way than making a separate checker function for every Boolean function with a different number of variables. For instance, we could make something like:

```
validR n bf :: Int -> (Bool -> a) -> Bool
validR n bf | n == 1    = valid1 bf 
            | otherwise = (validR (n-1) (bf True)) && (validR (n-1) (bf False))
```

where `n` is the number of variables in `bf`, the Boolean function that's being checked. When given a Boolean function `bf` with n>1 variables, this function would branch into checking `bf True` and `bf False`, eventually checking all possible truth-value combinations. But when I try to load this function Haskell gives the error message "Type error in application". Is there some way to tweak the type declaration of this function to make it work?

I'm new to Haskell so simple explanations would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this can be done quite easily.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances    #-}

class BooleanFunc f where
  isTautology :: f -> Bool

instance BooleanFunc Bool where
  isTautology = id
instance (BooleanFunc b) => BooleanFunc (Bool -> b) where
  isTautology f = isTautology (f True) && isTautology (f False)

main = do
   print . isTautology $ \a b c d -> True || a || b || c || d
   print . isTautology $ \a b c d ->         a || b || c || d
```

Comment: Try running hugs with the `-98` option. In general you're probably better off using `ghci`.